# SML/NJ Error: operator and operand don't agree

Tags: functional-programming, smlnj, type-parameter

I'm trying to write a function `contains` in SML/NJ:

```
fun contains(el: 'a, items: 'a list) =
  if null items
  then false
  else ((hd items) = el) orelse contains(el, tl items)
```

I'm aware I could probably achieve the same end result using native `list` functions, but this is for a MOOC that calls for not using any SML/NJ features beyond the basics it has covered thus far. The error I'm getting is:

```
solution.sml:10.9-10.24 Error: operator and operand don't agree [UBOUND match]
  operator domain: ''Z * ''Z
  operand:         'a * 'a
  in expression:
    hd items = el
```

I'm not 100% sure why I can't abstract over `'a` in the same way I can in `'a list`, I want `'a` to represent the same abstracted type in both instances. Am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ML, you cannot in general compare values of generic type such as `'a`. However, there is a special kind of generic types written `''a`, which stands for types that support equality testing using the `=` operator.

You can actually see that the error message is hinting at this by saying that `''Z * ''Z` does not match type `'a * 'a` - you explicitly defined the function as generic using `'a`, but the compiler would like it to be generic parameter `''Z` which allows comparison.

The following should do the trick:

```
fun contains(el: ''a, items: ''a list) =
  if null items
  then false
  else ((hd items) = el) orelse contains(el, tl items)
```